# How to trigger only web.config transformations via batch command in Jenkins

Tags: msbuild, batch-file, web-config, jenkins, config-transformation

I am setting up a Jenkins server to build .NET projects.  We our using the visual studio Web.config transformations to transform our config files for each environment (Dev1, Dev2, QA, and Release).  I am using the following command line arguments in my MSBuild command, and it is working with the transformations:

```
/p:Configuration=Dev1;DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Package;_PackageTempDir=..\..\deploy\current\Dev1
```

The problem is that I have to rebuild the solution for each environment, and some of the solutions are quite large and take a some time to build.  I would like to only build the solution once, and then trigger *just the transformations* for the other environments.  Does anyone know of a way to do this through an MSBuild batch command, or another way to get this done in Jenkins?

Comment: Seems to me that you should figure out how to do this without using Jenkins (i.e. from the command-line) and once you have only then incorporate the solution into Jenkins.

Comment: Agreed. That's what I'm trying to do. Jenkins is basically just executing command line commands.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using this [Config Transform Tool](http://ctt.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.  It did the trick easily by allowing us to run web.config transforms from a command line script that is easily executed by a Jenkins build step.

Comment: Thanks. This does the job. Only thing is the end result isn't pretty :-). Not sure why this approach is not the default. Have been looking around the web for the last 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, Jenkins just run the command. Take a look at the Task 5 of this [Exercise from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_webdevelopment_topic4.aspx). There's another approach [here](http://sedodream.com/2010/04/26/ConfigTransformationsOutsideOfWebAppBuilds.aspx).